# Access a webelement created in javascript

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I`m new using webdriver and I`m trying to access a webelement created in javascript. 
The webelement is created in a javascript: "view_mode":"application","shortname":"Kalender","sysname":"calendar","name":"Kalender".

I tried to find the element like this:

```
 WebElement button= driver.findElement(By.name("Kalender"));
 button.click();
```

And I got an error, telling me that the WebElement could not be found.

Comment: Let's see the HTML of the page then.

Comment: Show us the part of html code, please, or try to use firepath to determine it's XPath and try to evaluate it within FirePath to see if it is found and working. Also do not use Selenium PageFactory for ajax applications because it initializes the PageObject after the page is loaded which wont work if elements appear through javascript work

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this. It worked for me. 
((JavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementByName('Kalender').click()");